# How can I change the color of this object in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, logo

I have a jpg of gold glitter and I would like to add that as the background color of a circle thats part of my soon to be logo. Ive tried to add it as a "texture" under "transparency" but it comes up as black and white and not the gold glitter. I have no idea what I'm doing. I tried watching youtube tutorials but I'm still lost. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Place the image behind the circle. Select both circle and image. Right-click and select **Make Clipping Mask** (or press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>).

[image]

[image]